# How to communicate model attributes and/or data annotation to a vue.js

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, vue.js, crud, custom-attributes

I'm using DotNet, Entity framework and Vue.js.

**The missing puzzle piece is this: I'd like my Vue.js to be able to read/know the attributes I've applied to/in my models.**

Let's suppose I have models such as:

```
public class Entry
  {
    [Hidden]
    public int id { get; set; }
  }

public class Patient: Entry
  {
    [RamqFormat]
    public string ramq { get; set; }
    [NameFormat]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [PhoneFormat]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [EnumAtt("fr,en,sp")]
    public Lang preferedLang { get; set; }
  }

public class Question: Entry
  {
    [InstructionFormat]
    public string instruction { get; set; }
    [QuestionLabelFormat]
    public string label { get; set; }
    [ResponseFormat]
    public Response response { get; set; }
    [BoolFormat]
    public bool isOptional { get; set; }
  }
```

Then I use a generic CRUD controller which make the communication with a CRUD.vue which itself looks like this;

```
<template src="./Crud.html"/>

<script>
import ctrl from "./CrudCtrl";

export default {
  name: 'crud',
  data () {
      return {
      model: ''
      }
  },

  ... CRUD implementation ...
```

Everything works just fine, including the generic CRUD controller.

**Now the missing puzzle piece is this: I'd like my Vue.js to be able to read/know the attributes I've applied to/in my models.**

For instance; When displaying a field/property from my models with the [PhoneFormat] then Vue.js should be able to determined that it ought to display my field/property as a input field correctly inforcing a given phone format.

Or if it has attributes [EnumAtt("fr,en,sp")] it ought to be display as dropdownlist with the options ["fr", "en", "sp"]

Or if it has attributes [BoolFormat] it ought to be display as a checkbox.

Or if it has attributes [Hidden] then it ought to not be displayed.

**I'd rather not have to duplicate my models in a series of component.vue or model.js.**

*1: I thought of creating a DTO containing the model's attributes and thus passing that meta-info to the front-end via the Controller when reading a model*

*2: I thought of sending all the meta-info of each models to the front-end via the Controller on first page load or on startup.*

*Any better suggestions?*